# How to handle AppTokenCache of multi-tenant daemon service application using MSAL.NET

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

Is it possible to use the [MSAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) authentication library to handle multiple `AppTokenCache`s that are generated by a multi-tenant daemon service app (i.e. the Client Credential grant)?

In this scenario, I have to build (n) number of confidential client applications based on tenant ids and I need to maintain the tokens.

```
var confidentialClientApplication_001 = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId("TenantId__001")
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

var confidentialClientApplication_002 = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId("TenantId__002")
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();
```

...
...
...

```
var confidentialClientApplication_999 = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(clientId)
                    .WithTenantId("TenantId__999")
                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .Build();
```

[This document](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/token-cache-serialization#token-cache-for-a-daemon-app) implements a single confidential client application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a different tenant id when acquiring a token.

This should work:

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("client-id")
    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
    .WithClientSecret("secret")
    .Build();

var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new[]{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"})
    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Guid.Parse("target-tenant-id"))
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

So we specify "organizations" as the app authority, but then specify a specific tenant when acquiring a token.

Comment: We need to add URLSchemes in info.plist file using the ClientId. If we have different client ids then how to handle that? I have a single app that will be used by multiple customers, they have their own environment. Please advice.